# How qmake set .dll and .lib file output path respectively

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm a beginner of using qmake to create a project.
So how can I set the output of .lib and .dll file respectively when a library project?
I think is necessery that I can link the .lib file in other project from a path,and use the .dll file when executing in another path.
I have used cmake, it's possible. So I think qmake too. 
But I can't find the method in document,  anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [DESTDIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir) in your qmake file.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I try to set DLLDESTDIR and DESTDIR, and the .dll file is copied to the DLLDESTDIR. It's fine, but the .a file and .dll file also copied to the DESTDIR. I want .a file to a path and the .dll file to another path. Any advice?